# Issues with ALM Explorer 12.53

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

We recently started to use the ALM Explorer to access the web portal of ALM.  Upon installation, we have observed several issues.

1. Multiple authentication. When the SiteAdmin(LDAP Enabled) page is accessed, we are initially prompted with “Web Server Authentication.” Once we finish this step,  we get prompted for “Proxy Authentication.” After completing this we are directed to the log in portal of the website with a prompt "External Exception C015000F". If we close this and enter our Active Directory username and password, we are able to log in to the application. Is there a way to avoid these multiple authentications? Also, “Save TD Connection Settings” also does not work upon closing the browser.
2. Slowness in log in and log out. We have to wait more than minute to log in. Log out seems to be faster upon changing few security setting. But the slowness in log in still persists

**System Info:**
ALM: version 12.53, installed on Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2
IE Version: 11
ALM Explorer Version: 12.53

Greatly appreciate your input.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE: Proxy and Web Server authentication prompt.

Resolution:
1.  In your browser enter the Quality Center URL and include "/Apps/". URL would look like:http://QC_Server:8080/qcbin/Apps/

2. Click on “Webgate Customization Tool”
3. Select “Save” and then run the utility
4. Uncheck “Always ask for credentials” from “Proxy Credentials” and “Web Server Customization” sections

The above must done at the computer from which the user is trying to access ALM explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can block the prompts in the registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MercuryInteractive\TestDirector\WEB\OpenProxyDialog = N

and

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MercuryInteractive\TestDirector\WEB\OpenIISDialog = N